# Django form not rendered by auth_views.LoginView

Tags: django, authentication

I have a problem that is that Django is not rendering one of the fields of my Login form. I'm using the auth_views.LoginView view for user authentication, and even if I put my template, one of the fields does not appear in my html.

Url.py:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from Turnos import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'),
```

with views.login view it works perfectly

```
#path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
```

with auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html') doesn't render the email field

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
```

]

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from Turnos.forms import loginForm

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = loginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('nuevoTurno.html')
    else:
        form = loginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ['email', 'password']
```

Html:

```
<form action="/login/" method="post" novalidate>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="{{ form.email.label }}" class="">Email</label>

                            {% render_field form.email class+="form_control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="{{ form.password.label }}" class="">Password</label>

                            {% render_field form.password placeholder="Password" class+="form_control form-control-lg" %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-block">
                                Enviar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a href="#" style="color: #fff">Lost password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

the email field is not displayed with auth_views.loginview

sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a third part plugin to render individual form fields (I assume you have used `{% load widget_tweaks %}` in your `base.html` template.

Perhaps try:

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

...or...

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Or even...

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.email.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">Email</label>
    {{ form.email }}
</div>
```

If the above doesn't work, then it is time to debug why email isn't pulling through. Not sure if it's an ordering thing (unlikely):

```
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(), attrs={'class': "form_control form-control-lg", 'placeholder': "Email"}, required=True, )
```

^ I've also added the Django way of passing in attributes to your form fields.

Comment: yes, i used widget_tweaks. testing your solutions, I realized that when I render the whole form, the fields that it returns are: username and password. No email and password, I suppose the LoginView view of auth_views works with those forms, not the ones I defined.

Comment: Ahhh I see - so you'll likely see some validation errors as well in your view. You may need to create you own extended `User` model from the base `User` model imported here. Let me know if you need any help with this!